# Send form data using npm (BrowserSync), git and php

Tags: php, html, git, forms, validation

I recently coded my first website. I used npm and gulp to see the website in localhost with BrowserSync.

I did the form validation with JS, but now I'm stuck on how to send the form data to my email using php.

I watched millions of tutorials but cannot get my head around.

My questions seem pretty basic:

1. In my contact.html form, can I add a POST method with an action to "mail.php" and expect this to work in my localhost? (I'm not running my local with apache - just using BrowserSync) - If I need to run with apache, should I change all my html files to .php? (contact, about us, index...?)
2. I had all my html files in the src folder, but in order to deploy with git, it asks me to put the website files in the root folder. So I moved all my files from /src to the root /. Is this correct?

Thanks to everybody that can help me out here! :)

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: While PHP can execute html files, if they don't have PHP code, it's pointless to have them run through the PHP interpreter.  There should be a lot of resources out there on learning PHP and how to send mail through PHP, you'll have to show your work and a specific problem to get help here though.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to config php to handle sending emails. if you want to test it locally, there are many tools that can simulate it.
2. git does not tell you where to locate your files. 
   if you are running a server, where the config is set to the document root /var/www and you place your files in this directory, you will reach them on the link http://localhost/ if you place your files in the dir /var/www/src, you will reach them on http://localhost/src/ you can add a URL rewrite rule, to forward all (or just some specific) request from / -> /src OR you can set an alias on your web server. 
   And try to use some pre-installed web servers, for example wampp or lampp, they will make your life easier.